# How to prove $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/\log(n)$ can't be solved using the Master Theorem?

Tags: recursion, master-theorem

I have read (in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12119799/10306089) question) that this recursion can't be solved via Master Theorem.
But I couldn't find exact and complete proof why the Master Theorem does not apply.

Comment: There isn't much to prove.. you take the statement of the master Theorem and check whether the hypotheses needed to apply the theorem hold. Besides, this recurrence CAN be solved using the master theorem.

Comment: @Steven OK. how should we do this? I have problem proving that n/log(n) is not polynomially smaller than n^log(2,2)! It seems clear that the two other statements of Master Theorem does not hold.

Comment: See my answer.$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion can be written as:
$$
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n),
$$
where $a=b=2$ and $f(n) = n \log^{-1} n$. Defining $c_{crit} = \log_b a = 1$ you can see that $f(n) = \Theta( n^{c_{crit}} \log^k n)$ for $k=-1$, therefore [case 2b of the Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form) applies.
The solution to the recurrence is therefore:
$$T(n) = \Theta( n^{c_{crit}} \log \log n ) = \Theta( n \log \log n).$$

Comment: Very well! Thank you for your answer.  Actually I didn't know about the various cases in case b of Master Theorem. All I know about Master Theorem is [this](https://filebin.net/813mua9nx38bu0jx).  Can you help me with this? I want to show the first statement does not hold.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get why _This is clearly not true since f(n) grows more than linearly_ :((( So stupid of me :\  I think f(n) grows less than linearly because it is divided by log(n).  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the _polynomially_ in the context :\

Comment: Ohh, sorry. It was my mistake... somehow I had $n \log n$ in my mind... give me some time to write down why $1$ does not hold.

Comment: Thanks a million :)

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$ be any constant. We want to compare $n^{\log_b a} = n$ with $\frac{n}{\log n}$. You can do so by taking the limit of their ratio: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1-\epsilon}}{n / \log n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \log n}{n^{1+\epsilon}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n}{\epsilon n^{\epsilon-1}}  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon n^\epsilon} = 0$. This shows that $\frac{n}{\log n} \in \omega(n)$ and hence $\frac{n}{\log n} \not\in O(n)$.

Comment: Superb!  Thank you so much I got my answer completely :))